# WebSocketClient frozen when connecting to WebSocket (Spring WebFlux)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-websocket

I have written a sample to demo client/server communication with WebSocket protocol.

The server code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
class WebSocketServerApplication {

    @Bean
    fun webSocketMapping(mapper: ObjectMapper): HandlerMapping? {
        val map = mapOf("/ws/messages" to ChatSocketHandler(mapper))
        val simpleUrlHandlerMapping = SimpleUrlHandlerMapping().apply {
            urlMap = map
            order = 10
        }
        return simpleUrlHandlerMapping
    }

    @Bean
    fun handlerAdapter(): WebSocketHandlerAdapter = WebSocketHandlerAdapter()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<WebSocketServerApplication>(*args)
}

class ChatSocketHandler(val mapper: ObjectMapper) : WebSocketHandler {
    val sink = Sinks.replay<Message>(100);
    val outputMessages: Flux<Message> = sink.asFlux();

    override fun handle(session: WebSocketSession): Mono<Void> {
        println("handling WebSocketSession...")
        session.receive()
                .map { it.payloadAsText }
                .map { Message(id= UUID.randomUUID().toString(), body = it, sentAt = Instant.now()) }
                .doOnNext { println(it) }
                .subscribe(
                        { message: Message -> sink.next(message) },
                        { error: Throwable -> sink.error(error) }
                );

        return session.send(
                Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                        .thenMany(outputMessages.map { session.textMessage(toJson(it)) })

        )

    }

    fun toJson(message: Message): String = mapper.writeValueAsString(message)

}

data class Message @JsonCreator constructor(
        @JsonProperty("id") var id: String? = null,
        @JsonProperty("body") var body: String,
        @JsonProperty("sentAt") var sentAt: Instant = Instant.now()
)
```

I have provided a client written in Angular, it works well, the codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-websocket-sample/tree/feat/reactor-sinks/client).

When trying to a test for the server.

```java
@SpringBootTest()
class WebsocketServerApplicationTests {

    lateinit var client: WebSocketClient;

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        this.client = ReactorNettyWebSocketClient()
    }

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
        val replay = Sinks.replay<Message>(10)

        client.execute(
                URI("ws://localhost:8080/ws/messages")
        ) { session: WebSocketSession ->
            println("Starting to send messages")
            session.receive()
                    .map { mapper.readValue(it.payloadAsText, Message::class.java) }
                    .subscribe { replay.next(it) }

            session.send(
                    Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).thenMany(
                            Flux.just("test message", "test message2")
                                    .map(session::textMessage)
                    )
            ).then()
        }.subscribe()

        StepVerifier.create(replay.asFlux().takeLast(2))
                .consumeNextWith { it -> assertThat(it.body).isEqualTo("test message") }
                .consumeNextWith { it -> assertThat(it.body).isEqualTo("test message2") }
                .verifyComplete()
    }
}
```

When starting up the application, run the test, it is frozen, not work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on the test side.

## Complete your stream to make `takeLast(n)` working

First of all, you expect to take the last 2 elements from the stream. However, that is going to happen when and only when there is `onComplete` signal, which let the `Flux.takeLast` know that there is the end of the stream, so the last `n` observed elements are *last*.

In your code, you listen to the `WebsocketInbound` messages and send them to the `ReplaySink`. However, the `FluxSink#complete` message is never called, which means `takeLast(2)` will hang forever as expected.

## Solution

On the one hand, the solution seems to be obvious:

```java
session.receive()
       .map { mapper.readValue(it.payloadAsText, Message::class.java) }
       .subscribe ({ replay.next(it) }, { replay.error(it) }, { replay.complete() })
```

However, there is might be a trick:
`.receive` sends a terminal signal only when the WebSocket connection is closed.

Therefore, in order to receive a terminal signal, please ensure that the server closes the connection on its side. Otherwise, the test will still hang waiting for the final terminal signal.

**If the connection close is not desired, try to simply use `.take(2)`.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this issue myself after reading some posts on stackoverflow and source codes of testing reactive WebSocket in the spring framework.

- [Spring reactive ReactorNettyWebSocketClient not logging anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467913/spring-reactive-reactornettywebsocketclient-not-logging-anything)
- [How to use Spring Reactive WebSocket and transform it into the Flux stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065219/how-to-use-spring-reactive-websocket-and-transform-it-into-the-flux-stream)
- [WebSocketIntegrationTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/WebSocketIntegrationTests.java)

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest()
class WebSocketServerApplicationTests {

    lateinit var client: WebSocketClient

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        this.client = ReactorNettyWebSocketClient()
    }

   @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
        val replay = Processors.replay<Message>(100)
        try {
            client.execute(
                    URI("ws://localhost:8080/ws/messages")
            ) { session: WebSocketSession ->

                val receiveMono = session.receive()
                        .map { mapper.readValue(it.payloadAsText, Message::class.java) }
                        .log("received from server::")
                        .subscribeWith(replay)
                        .then()
                session
                        .send(
                                Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(500)).thenMany(
                                        Flux.just("test message", "test message2")
                                                .map(session::textMessage)
                                )
                        )
                        .then(receiveMono)
            }.block(Duration.ofSeconds(5L))

            // assert
            assertThat(replay.blockLast(Duration.ofSeconds(5L))?.body).isEqualTo("test message2")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.message)
        }
    }
}
```